# Why is it that only my horizontal scroll bar hides but my vertical scroll bar does not?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have these css entries ...

```
div { overflow: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; overflow-x: hidden;}
div:hover { overflow:visible; overflow-y: visible; overflow-x: visible;}
```

... hoping that the vertical and horizontal scroll bars would only appear when a user mouses into a rectangle.  But the above is only working for my horizontal scroll bar.

Mouse outside of rectangle: horizontal scroll hidden, vertical visible

[image]

Mouse inside `san` rectangle: horizontal scroll bar appears.

[image]

Update: The html for my list is:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href=...>blah blah blah</a></li>
    <li><a href=...>blah blah blah</a></li>
    <li><a href=...>blah blah blah</a></li>
    ...
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Update: Using ...

```
div { overflow: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; overflow-x: hidden; width:300px;height:200px; }
div:hover { overflow:scroll; overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: scroll;}
```

Did not work for me.  Here is what my `san` rectangle looks like before I mouse over it:

[image]

Both horizontal and vertical scrolls appear.  Here's what my `san` rectangle looks like on mouse over:

[image]

The scroll bars stay but the text disappears!

Comment: Could you please also provide your HTML?

Answer (score 4):

For scroll bars you need to use scroll not visible. Visible shows the content, scroll enables the scrollbars.

```css
div { overflow: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; overflow-x: hidden;

width:300px;height:200px;
}
div:hover { overflow:scroll; overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: scroll;}
```

```html
<div>
asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada 
asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada 
asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada 
asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada 
asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada 
asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada 
asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada 
asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada 
asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada 
asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada 
asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada 
asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada 
asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada 
asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada 
asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada 
asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada 
asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada asdsada 
</div>
```

Comment: This didn't work for me.  The text inside my rectangles was not visible until I moused over the rectangle.  I have updated my question with the html I am using for the list.

Answer (score 1):

use `{overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none; }` if Firefox and `::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 0 !important }` if Chrome/Safari or newer Opera.